# How to use imdpd to import data file into different schema including index from different tablespace as well

Tags: oracle, import, restore

The original data pump file is generated by the schema which living in two tablespaces(`OLD_SCHEMA_DAT` and `OLD_SCHEMA_IDX`), if import back to the original tablespace, everything is fine, but when I use following command:

```
impdp OLD_USER/OLD_PASS dumpfile=whole.package.dmp directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
REMAP_SCHEMA=ORIGINAL_SCHEMA:NEW_SCHEMA
```

It works but with 200 errors stating that

```
ORA-39083: Object type CONSTRAINT failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'OLD_SCHEMA_IDX' does not exist
```

it looks for the original index tablespace instead of the new one, and even I tried:

```
impdp OLD_USER/OLD_PASS dumpfile=whole.package.dmp directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR
REMAP_TABLESPACE=OLD_SCHEMA_DAT:NEW_SCHEMA_DAT
REMAP_TABLESPACE=OLD_SCHEMA_IDX:NEW_SCHEMA_IDX
```

Still did not resolve the problem, then what to do? I am on 11g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one REMAP_TABLESPACE parameter in de command. 
It would be seperated with ",".
REMAP_TABLESPACE=OLD_SCHEMA_DAT:NEW_SCHEMA_DAT,OLD_SCHEMA_IDX:NEW_SCHEMA_IDX

Oracle doc impdp 11.2
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL929